# Show images for each attribute selection in Magento 1.9.3

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute

I have an attribute named "Special"

For each selection of this attribute I want to show some icons-images in the frontend of the product.

For this specific product I want to have a "Bio Product" icon, a "Gluten free" icon and a "Salt free" icon

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While displaying those selected attribute values. Arrange them as separate span sections and give the class name same as selected value. Write css for each individual class and assign background image. To be more clear. For the screenshot you attached generate span like below.

```
<span class='bio'></span>

<span class='gluten-free'></span>

<span class='salt-free'></span>
```

Write CSS as below but for all possible values for the attribute.

```
.bio{background-image:......}
.gluten-free{background-image:......}
.salt-free{background-image:......}
```

Please note that you cannot apply this as it is. This will help you to understand the approach. Use it as per your requirement with required changes.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the response.
<br>This must be automated in every product, when I select a Special on the backened

Comment: Hi, once you add background images for all possible attribute values in CSS, icons will display automatically . Once it is set, it will work always for any set of selected special attribute values.

can you please clarify what you mean by automate?